# Rstudio Notebook (rmarkdown) running python: describe not shown

Tags: python, r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am runing some python chunks in a Rstudio notebook, which include reading a csv file and printing basic statistics. I could not find the way to print the statistics (describe()) as an output. 
Here is the code:

````
```{python, engine.path = '/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3'}
   import pandas
   data_py = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/datafiles/data.csv', sep= ';')
```

```{python, engine.path = '/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3'}
   data_py.describe(include='all')
```
````

NO output printed. 
I also tried:

````
 ```{python, engine.path = '/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3'}
    print(data_py.describe(include='all'))
```
````

and

````
 ```{python, engine.path = '/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3'}
    summary = data_py.describe(include='all')
    print(summary)
```
````

with no success.
Any help?

Comment: Related to http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html#comment-2935043857 ?

Comment: Not really. I have changed the code to include everything in one chunk:      ```{python, engine.path = '/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3'}
import pandas
data_py = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/datafiles/data.csv', sep= ';')
data_py.describe(include='all')

```    with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out the code you wrote works if you put in your .Renviron file:

> PYTHONPATH=/home/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Change the path to your site-packages (or where packages are)

> `{python} 
>   import pandas 
>   data_py = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', sep= ';') 
>   data_py.describe(include='all') 
>   summary =
>   data_py.describe(include='all') 
>   print( summary)`