# Python output not appearing in RMarkdown

Tags: python, r-markdown

I'm having a problem similar to this question: [Rstudio Notebook (rmarkdown) running python: describe not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512587/rstudio-notebook-rmarkdown-running-python-describe-not-shown)

I have the following code chunk:

````
```{python, engine.path = 
"C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/continuum/anaconda2/python.exe"}
import pandas as pd
helpdf = pd.read_stata('c:/book/help.dta')

print helpdf

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
helplm = smf.ols(formula='i1 ~ substance * age', data=helpdf).fit()            
helplm.summary()
helplm.params
```
````

The print works fine in RMarkdown, so pandas is being read in.  Running this interactively generates the desired statsmodels output.

I'm a total Python novice.

Comment: I don't know Rstudio notebook, but maybe you are missing the print, eg. `print(helplm.summary())`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.  Not sure why it would need explicit printing there, though.

Comment: Is there a way around it? I'd like to write `1+1` in a python code chunk and having it rendered without having to write `print(1+1)`.