# Python in RMarkdown

Tags: python, r-markdown

I was trying to execute Python in RMarkdown. While the code chunk is giving an output perfectly fine while executing it separately using the **Run current chunk** button, it is not getting executed while knitting the document. Below is a simple replication of the code chunk

`{python engine.path='~/anaconda3/bin/python3',python.reticulate=F}
x=[1,2,3]
print(x)`

Below is the error message I'm getting

`running: ~/anaconda3/bin/python3  -c '
x=[1,2,3,4]
print(x)'
Quitting from lines 14-17 (Error_demo.Rmd) 
Error in system2(cmd, code, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env = options$engine.env) : 
  error in running command
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted`

I even tried adding `PYTHONPATH` to `.Renviron` file as mentioned in the response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512587/rstudio-notebook-rmarkdown-running-python-describe-not-shown) question. But that too didn't seem to help. Can some please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should do (it worked for me):

```
library(reticulate)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```

Details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/r_markdown.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.